# Swedish letters display as special characters in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am showing swedish letters in an alert box title, but it is showing the swedish letters in special characters.

For example, I am showing this word as an alert box title:

> Arbetsförändring

But it is showing like

> Arbetsf�r�ndring

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You basically want to set the "Culture" properties on your ASP.Net page:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx

To set the encoding for all pages, you can set the "Globalization" property in web.config:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39d1w2xf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Here is the root page for ASP.Net Globalization and Localization:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

'Hope that helps!

Comment: it doesn't helps me out. i have already used the globalization info in my config file.

Comment: Still my problem not yet solved. Can anybody please?